# Parabolic Interpolation using optim()

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to find minimum of a given function using parabolic interpolation.

**Objective:**

Using a function 'g(x)' find the minimum of another function 'f(x)'

- Function used to estimate -> g(x) = a0+a1*x + a2*x^2
- Function whose minimum needs to be found -> f(x) = -x(1-x)
- Find paramaters a0,a1,a2 such that f(x0)=g(x0), f(x1)=g(x1), f(x2)=g(x2) for three given x1,x2 and x3.

**Constraints:**

- x0,x1,x2 belong in range of (0,1)

**Plot:**

[image: Plot of f(x) and g(x), where f(x) is given by dots and g(x) is given by lines]

**Theoretical Result:**

- From the plot its clear that the function (f(x)) is minimum at 0.5
- If a0=0,a1=-1,a2=1 we basically get g(x)=f(x)

**Result provide by code:**

- a0 <- 13661.814
- a1 <- 7221.972
- a2 <- -2475.557

**Key Question:**

- Is my understanding of this method correct or is the issue in my
  code?

**Attempted Solution:**

I have done the following but my values makes no sense

```
# Actual function to estimate the minimum value of
actual <- function(x){
  result <- -x *(1-x)
return(result)  
}

# The estimation function whose parameters a0,a1,a2 are unknown
parabola <- function(par,x){
  a0 <- par[1]
  a1 <- par[2]
  a2 <- par[3]
  result <- a0+a1*x+a2*x^2
return(result)
}

# finding the difference between the functions for three given values (x0,x1,x2)
difference_function <- function(par,x){
  x0 <- par[4]
  x1 <- par[5]
  x2 <- par[6] 
  result <- sum(actual(x0),actual(x1),actual(x2)) - sum(parabola(par,x0),parabola(par,x1),parabola(par,x2)) 
  return(result)
}

find_parameters <- function(){
temp <- optim(par=c(0,-1,1,0.4,0.55,0.6), fn=difference_function)
a0 <- temp$par[1]
a1 <- temp$par[2]
a2 <- temp$par[3]
return(list=c(a0=a0,a1=a1,a2=a2))
}

find_parameters()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was to minimize the squared error, since this would provide a unique solution

The corrected solution is as follows:

```
# Actual function to estimate the minimum value of
actual <- function(x){
  result <- -x *(1-x)
return(result)  
}

# The estimation function whose parameters a0,a1,a2 are unknown
parabola <- function(par,x){
  a0 <- par[1]
  a1 <- par[2]
  a2 <- par[3]
  result <- a0+a1*x+a2*x^2
return(result)
}

# finding the difference between the functions for three given values (x0,x1,x2)
difference_function <- function(par,x){
  x0 <- par[4]
  x1 <- par[5]
  x2 <- par[6] 
  result <- sum((actual(x0)-parabola(par,x0))^2,(actual(x1)-parabola(par,x1))^2, (actual(x2)-parabola(par,x2))^2)
  return(result)
}

find_parameters <- function(){
temp <- optim(par=c(0,-1,1,0.1,0.8,0.9), fn=difference_function)
a0 <- temp$par[1]
a1 <- temp$par[2]
a2 <- temp$par[3]
return(list=c(a0=a0,a1=a1,a2=a2))
}

find_parameters()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in a broader mathematical sense, 3 points aren't enough to uniquely define a parabola. 5 points should be enough to uniquely define any conic section. See:

https://www.quora.com/How-many-points-are-needed-to-uniquely-define-a-parabola-and-the-other-conics-Is-there-only-one-parabola-passing-through-the-vertices-of-a-given-triangle

Unless you have enough points to uniquely define the parabola there will be multiple answers to your optimization.

Comment: This is technique to estimate minima of a function in the similar way of newton method. Here is a great video on the same: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6ikEASjbWE and wikipedia link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_parabolic_interpolation